# How to check whether Pylint setup is OK

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint, linter

How can I check if Pylint is successfully installed and configured in Visual Studio Code?

I have already set "Python: enable linting", but it seems to not be working. I ran code in the below *problem* field. Can someone explain what's going on in the below *problem* field?

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhktK.png)

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWlHF.png)

Comment: Are you using global environment?

Comment: Can you crop and reduce those images (in preparation for making them inline)? That is, only include the parts that are actually needed.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Check** if `Pylint` is installed successfully:

   As a Python code analysis toolkit, Pylint is stored in the Python environment as a Pylint module, so we can use "`pip show pylint`" in the Visual Studio Code terminal to check its installation:

   [image]
2. The **use** of `Pylin`t in Visual Studio Code:

   1. Install Pylint (`pip install pylint`).
   2. Select Pylint.

      [image]
   3. Enable Pylint.
   4. Run (<kbd>F1</kbd>, `Python: Run Linting`)

      [image]

Reference: [Linting in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting).

Comment: `pip3 show pylint` on Ubuntu (tried on [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa)) - "pip3", not "pip". `pip show pylint` results in *"Command 'pip' not found, but there are 18 similar ones."* (including in a Visual Studio Code environment).